# How do I prove this vector calculus identity using component notation?

Tags: vector-analysis

I wish to show that

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (A \times B) = B \cdot(\nabla \times A)- A \cdot(\nabla \times B),
\end{equation}

using component notation. Here is what I have thus far

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\nabla \cdot (A \times B) =& \nabla \cdot (a_i b_j \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{e_k}) \\
=& \partial_m (a_i b_j \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{e_k})_m.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I am stuck after this step. I don't know how to 'introduce the product rule' into the bracketed component.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: There was a typo in the first equation that has been corrected.

Comment: Hint: $ \partial_m (a_i b_j \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{e_k})_m= \partial_k(a_i b_j \epsilon_{ijk})=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_k(a_i b_j )$, being $(\hat{e_k})_m=\delta_{mk} $

Comment: Thank you very much this was all the information I needed to complete this proof.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\nabla\cdot (A \times B) =  \partial_k(A \times B)_k= \partial_k(a_i b_j \epsilon_{ijk})=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_k(a_i b_j)=\\
=\epsilon_{ijk}b_j\partial_k a_i+\epsilon_{ijk}a_i\partial_k b_j=\\
=b_j(\epsilon_{kij}\partial_k a_i)-a_i(\epsilon_{kji}\partial_k b_j)=\\
=b_j(\nabla\times A)_j-a_i(\nabla\times B)_i=\\
= B \cdot(\nabla \times A)- A \cdot(\nabla \times B),
$$
having used $\epsilon_{ijk}=\epsilon_{kij} $ and $\epsilon_{ijk}=-\epsilon_{kji} $.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed proof I appreciate it.